# Error: Eclipse does not generate the .class file

Tags: java, eclipse

Although I have come across several similar questions on this, but the issues / solutions are different from mine.

In my case, this occur if my Java code is long, and when I checked the bin folder, the class file is not there.

If I commend some of the lines in my Java code, everything works fine, and the class file is at the bin folder after I do Run As -> Java Application.

Once I uncommend those lines and do Run As -> Java Application again, the error will come back, and the class file at the bin folder disappears.

Is there any limitation on the number of lines we can have in a Java file?

Below is what I get from the Error Log:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File not found: C:\Users\edwin\workspace\Solr_6.4\bin\testing.class.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:55)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.openInputStream(LocalFile.java:377)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:797)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:289)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.getResourceContentsAsByteArray(Util.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.writeClassFileCheck(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:888)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.writeClassFileContents(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:830)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.writeClassFile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:857)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.acceptResult(AbstractImageBuilder.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:510)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.compile(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:329)
```

Regards,
Edwin

Comment: What does the compiler say? If the compiler is ot able to compile a class, it tells it, with an error message. Read it and post it.

Comment: @TahirHussainMir Obviously the size of the Java source file seems to be an issue (at least, OP thinks so). Do you really think that posting such a large class here serves any good?

Comment: The compiler only states "Error: Could not find or load main class". I have included the error log above.

Comment: @EdwinYeo This is not the _compiler_ error. It is a _runtime_ error when you try to run a program that is not there. JB Nizet tries to explain you _why_ it possibly is not there: Maybe there are compiler errors and the binary file is not created as a result.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The weird thing is that I did not get any compiler error displayed, and that there is no error pointed out in the code.